# Is this a good way to check if only one instance of a class exists without resorting to using the Singleton pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton

I have a class in my program of which I want only one copy.  I don't want to use the Singleton pattern though for a couple of reasons (* see below).  I know that I'll only have one copy of the class because I'll be the only one calling its constructor.

In my class's constructor, I want to check that only one copy of the class will exist and throw an exception if more than one exists.  Is the code below a good pattern to use for this case?

```
public class MySingletonAlternative : IDisposable
{
    private static int _count = 0;

    public MySingletonAlternative()
    {
        int newValue = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
        if (newValue > 1)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        int newValue = System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(ref _count);
        if (newValue < 0)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("MySingletonAlternative");
        }
    }
}
```

---

* Why I don't want to use a Singleton:

1. I want to be able to control when the class is created.  In the traditional C# Singleton pattern, construction happens non-deterministically.
2. I want to avoid global variables.
3. When I'm debugging my code and an exception is raised in the Singleton's private constructor, Visual Studio highlights the exception, but it highlights the wrong line of code, usually in a different file.
4. I don't want to create this object lazily (using Lazy<T>).  One instance of this class will exist for the life of my application.  I gain nothing by constructing it lazily.

Comment: If you have a static constructor, the construction of the normal singleton is entirely deterministic. And you still have a global variable: the counter. It's not at all clear *why* you want to prevent more than one instance ever being created. That has some of the downsides of the singleton pattern (lack of testability for example) without some of the dubious benefits.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx  `The user has no control on when the static constructor is executed in the program.`  Also, I wouldn't call the counter global considering that I've declared it private.

Comment: That's just untrue. It's *somewhat* true of type initializers for types without a static constructor present, but when there's a static constructor, the C# spec is quite clear: "The execution of a static constructor is triggered by the first of the following events to occur within an application domain: - An instance of the class type is created. - Any of the static members of the class type are referenced."

Comment: See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx for more details.

Comment: IdentityMap keyed by type?

Comment: There is literally no reason for the class to care how many other instances exist. Leave it to the *user* of the class to decide how to best *use* it.

Comment: @jalf I was originally using the Singleton pattern, but I found that I didn't like it for some of the reasons I mentioned.  I like that it enforces there being only one instance of the class, but I don't like some of the other features, nor how Visual Studio handles static constructors while debugging.  Given that I am both the implementer and the user of the class, I figure my alternative pattern is ok.

Comment: @user2023861 no, *you now* is the implementer and *you later* is the user. You can make your class simpler by removing the check for how many instances exist. If you just need one instance now, just *create* one instance. If, later on, you decide you need two instances, *then the class will allow you to do that*. The point is, you can write your code to be simple and flexible, or you can make it more complex to write *and* less flexible to use, which might hurt you later on when you realize you actually want to use it in in slightly different ways (perhaps with more than one instance existing)

Answer (score 0):

Use a IoC Container like an [UnityContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430868%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx). It will erase all of your points you've mentioned why you don't want to use a Singleton (in the means of global variables or `static`). You will be able to fully controll the creation of your lifetime-instance and inject it into all classes that will need to use this.

Answer (score -1):

Can you use dependency injection and then have the di container manage the lifetime of the class you want to create? an example is with Unity and the ContainerControlledLifetimeManager

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec34

Comment: I think a dependency injection solution would be much more robust than I need.  I'm also not sure it would solve my problem.  My project is small, and I won't often be replacing components or dependencies.  My problem is ultimately that I need one instance of a class for the life of my application.  This class holds some data and makes network calls. I don't want duplicate data or unnecessary network calls; hence exactly one instance of the class.

Comment: DI isn't big or difficult to add to your project. From what you have said, it will solve all the problems you have listed and is not purely about swapping things out based on configuration - but makes you write your code in a more testable manner while removing the inherent evil of singleton classes as it is possible to have that aspect of your application managed for you. As a matter of fact, if you are not used to DI, then starting out with it in a small project is the easiest way to get to grips with it. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: it's funny, the way that I was going to use MySingletonAlternative is similar to what I've read about Dependency Injection examples.  I just didn't know it was called that until you mentioned it.  The examples that I've read about online do seem too robust for me, but what I'm thinking of doing with classes that need my lifetime object is for them to have a setter which I'll use to set this dependency once it's constructed (it takes a little bit to construct the lifetime object).  Thanks.

Comment: it wasn't me.  I don't even remember why I asked this question

Answer (score -1):

**DON'T USE THIS CODE BELOW IN REAL APPLICATIONS! It's just for demo purposes.**

I guess it's not a good way, but it looks like that your approach will work just fine. I am not aware of edge cases though.

Just created a little test app to create 1 million instances in  a `for loop` and count
the exceptions it raises.
In this case it should be: 1 instance successfully created and `999.000` exceptions raised.

I ran the test app a couple of times and it always returned `999.000`.
Depending on your machine this code could take some time to finish,
cause it throws `999.000` exceptions.

```
public static volatile int _global_Exception_count = 0;
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    _global_Exception_count = 0;

    var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000).ToList();

    var tlist = list.Select(async item =>
     {
         MySingletonAlternative current = null;

         try
         {
             current = new MySingletonAlternative();
         }
         catch (Exception ex) { System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _global_Exception_count); }

         return await Task.FromResult(0);
     });
    await Task.WhenAll(tlist);

    Console.WriteLine(_global_Exception_count);
}// end main
```

Comment: An Anonymous downvoter just downvoted whole the thread from top to bottom.
I appreciate your comment, at least a reason would be nice...